# I'm getting double curves in Animation Nodes loop

Tags: animation-nodes

In not good in programming, but I'm trying hard and get some results. I'm trying to make a lot of curves from 1 point to points of other objects. And it works fine, but some curves double and I don't know why.
Can somebody help me find the mistake ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through your node tree, your list of vectors creating the spline contains 12 vectors (top right list).

I think what you're trying to do is to alternate between the "point 1" and each of the 6 ship locations, and draw a curve from point 1 to each location.

However, because your node tree puts all the vectors into one list, it draws a single spline through all of those points.

If we think of the 6 ship locations as A-F, your spline is drawing

A->1->B->1->C->1->D->1->E->1->F->1

as a single spline, without "picking up the pen."

So, for instance, the spline draws from 1 to B then back to 1, doubling up.  With your smoothness of .04, this will show up as a very flattened oval, which will look like 2 lines.

You can probably see this better if you turn off the Bevel Depth temporarily.

You can cheat this by just making your smoothness = 0, and it will mostly work and draw straight lines (one over the other.)

To get separate splines for each curve, you'll need to iterate through the vector pairs and create them individually.. you can't just put them all into one spline.

HTH.

Z